# Bootstrap Collapsed div initial display property is empty

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was working through an example, and I came across this.

I had a div set initially to be collapsed, and then checked its status from a javascript function. I was initially testing for "none", and it wasn't working. After some testing, I found that testing for "" did work.
Is this standard, or is it something I'm doing?

Working version:

```
<div id="menuItem" class="well collapse">
    <p id="itemDesc">test</p>
</div>
...
function showItem(itemName){
if (document.getElementById('menuItem').style.display == ""){ 
    document.getElementById('menuItem').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard via the method you are using.  `document.getElementById('element').style.display` only checks the styles that live on the element and since no display style lives on that element it is returning `""`.  To get the computed styles (i.e. from the style sheet) on an element you need to use the property `getComputedStyle` (or `currentStyle` for IE).

This question/answer has some really good info on the difference and a good function for how to check:

[myDiv.style.display returns blank when set in master stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748813/mydiv-style-display-returns-blank-when-set-in-master-stylesheet)

Comment: Ahh, I guess that makes sense. Thanks for your quick response!