# html show hide div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to `show/hide` div in html now I'm using w3schools Toggle Hide and Show [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp). It is working good but by default it shows condition I what by default hide condition if I press show button it should show.
help me.

**code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the following changes in your code. Add a `display:none` for **#myDIV** in css to hide it on initial loading. But if you still check in JS (x.style.display), you will get an empty string instead of none. That's beacause the style attribute does not have any setting for display until the code is run through the first time. So to handle this case you need to update your if condition as well like this - `if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display === "")`

You can check here for more info - [Similar Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748813/mydiv-style-display-returns-blank-when-set-in-master-stylesheet)

I have attached a snippet. Hope that's how you want it to work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display === "") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```

Comment: Hi, the solution is fine but a bit of explanation might help future readers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add display: none to the div css,

```
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

and change the if condition to this:

```
if (x.style.display == "none" || x.style.display === "")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as adding to the stylesheet does not change the value of the element's style property.

Comment: I tried it now, check this link please https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-tkobyk?file=index.html

Comment: @yoelb00 thank you is there possible else of button can I use check box

Comment: It does not work the first time - this is because the style attribute does not have any setting for display until the code is run through the first time. See the answer from @ankitsaxina for the correct way to do it.

Comment: Do you want to replace the button with checkbox ?

Comment: @yoelb00 i what to replace button to checkbox

Comment: replace <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> with <input onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" value="1">
<label for="vehicle1"> Try it</label> , you can see the change here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-tkobyk?file=index.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest do not update the style property directly, but toggle a class "hidden" instead. Here is a snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  x.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <div id="myDIV" class="hidden">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If this does not solve your problem, please let me know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add display:none; to your style and add  document.addEventListener on page load  to your js as the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    #myDIV {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");

        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        myFunction();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```