# OnClick button needs clicking twice to work?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Very new to JS so bear with me - I'm trying to make a show/hide section on a page. It's working - but it needs to be clicked twice to work. I've looked at event handling and tried a couple examples I found on here but it's not working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("topsection");
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(x);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#topsection {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="topsection">
        This is a DIV element.
        </div>

<div id="section3">
    <button class="togglebutton" onclick="myFunction()">
        <img src="image.png" alt="buttonpng";>
    </button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I;ve placed your code into a runnable snippet, seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @0stone0 - apologies, I forgot to add the CSS in, in the CSS I have the 'topsection' as display: none - and I think this is what's causing the issue, but I want the section to be hidden until the button is clicked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the CSS to mimic a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [myDiv.style.display returns blank when set in master stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748813/mydiv-style-display-returns-blank-when-set-in-master-stylesheet)

Comment: @0stone0 updated, and the issue is now present in the snippet too. I've gone through the page you sent and it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: Well this is an exact duplicate, your solution is in the first answer of that linked question.

Comment: @0stone0 - Added 'display:none' into the div itself and it worked. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked, you could also do `if ((x?.style?.display || "none") === "none")` or use `getComputedStyle` with a fallback. Please mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

In the code, style.display property returns an empty string if the inline style is not set. in your code, when you first click x.style.display is an empty string. To fix it, you can use window.getComputedStyle instead of style.display.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("topsection");
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(x);

  if (computedStyle.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="topsection">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>

<div id="section3">
  <button class="togglebutton" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img src="image.png" alt="buttonpng" />
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `if (x.style.display === "none") {`

`x.style.display` is **undefined** the first time you run the code not a **string** --> `"none"`

And so, if you change that conditional statement for `if(!x.style.display)` or `if(x.style.display == undefined)` it will work with just one click.

**Why is it working with two clicks?**

It is because the first time you run the code the if statement is not met and so, the `else {}` is executed defining that specific style to `"none"`.

And so you get what happends the second time you click. Right?

**Second issue**

Replace your `else { x.style.display = "none"}` for `else {x.style.display = null}` so that you undefine the style prop

You can also achieve the same thing by using: `x.style.removeProperty('display')`

Comment: YAY sorted! Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Then it wont work the second time

Comment: @0stone0 - I just noticed that - it is working the first time but it won't 'show' again after it's been hidden.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just use a fallback for the empty string

Comment: @poppythewitch updated. it will work now, all the time ;)

Comment: null is not a valid css value..... use unset

Answer (score -1):

Mitesh Dudhat has the correct answer to fix your immediate problem but there is another solution.

If you swap out your `id` for a class and use a separate class set to `display: block` you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) that class on/off.

The reason for swapping out the id for a class is due to ids [ranking higher in specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css) in the CSS cascade - using a class means that you wouldn't need to add an `!important` property to the new class rule.

Note: in this example I've removed the inline JavaScript and used [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to cache the DOM elements, and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a listener to the button.

```js
const section = document.querySelector('.topsection');
const button = document.querySelector('.togglebutton');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  section.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.topsection {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="topsection">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>

<div id="section3">
  <button class="togglebutton">
    Toggle section    
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: there are many different ways of solving a problem. There is nothing like just one solution. You are making a major change on the code of the OP rather than giving hints to improve his errors and answer his question.

Comment: And why not just close as one of the many duplicates?