# html css link import order and overriding

Tags: html, css, import

I have to define four css imports in a file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="not screen and (device-width: 1200px) and (device-height: 900px)"
  href="lib/sugar-web/graphics/css/sugar-96dpi.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (device-width: 1200px) and (device-height: 900px)"
  href="lib/sugar-web/graphics/css/sugar-200dpi.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
  href="lib/sugar-web/graphics/css/sugar-200dpi.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/activity.css">
```

I want, the simple screen media css (third line  : without any condition) to be imported only if the above screen media definitions fail.
Is the order of  tags correct ?

(What I want to avoid, is that third screen css is loaded in any case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tried to search your issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724606/js-how-to-load-css-if-not-loaded)

what you exactly mean with 'without any conditions' ? if none of the media querys is firing none if the linked css files will be imported. for that your order is the right one.

is this the answer?!

Comment: Thanks. The link you gave me did not appear (as purposition) when I was editing my question. And I don't find that it related to my question. Without any condition => without and/or

Comment: yes.. it´s not related as the answer i gave you is enough to answer your question :)