# Using PHP to check if a CSS stylesheet is active for if/else statement

Tags: php, css, if-statement

This is a strange one and it might not even be possible, but what I'm trying to do is check whether a particular stylesheet is loaded, if it is run one code, else run another. For example:

```
// Create loop counter
$counter = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) {
    // MaxIT - Shows 2 listings per loop instead of 2
    for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {

        // Increase loop counter
        $counter++;

        the_post();

        // Include listing loop template
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'listing' );

    } // endwhile have_posts()

    echo '<hr style="width:100%; padding-left: 40px; margin: 60px 0px;" />';
}
```

The point of this code is to display properties on a real estate website. The original code did not have the FOR loop, I added that in so it would display 2 properties at a time before displaying in a horizontal rule. This was purely for aesthetics and looks great when viewing the properties in "grid" view, which shows two properties per row, like:

PROPERTY | PROPERTY

HORIZONTAL RULE

However, the client requested having a list view also, which shows 1 property per row, with image on the left and details on the right. I accomplished this with a second stylesheet which is loaded on click of a drop-down selector. However, because the above PHP loads 2 properties before the HR, it shows like:

PROPERTY

PROPERTY

HORIZONTAL RULE

So what I want to accomplish is having the PHP say "if the grid_view.css is loaded, show 2 properties before the HR, else if the list_view.css is loaded, show 1 property before the HR".

Is this possible with PHP? I'm not familiar with any other programming languages, so if it can be done in Javascript / JQuery that would be fine but I might need the "dummy" explanation if possible.

Thanks heaps in advance!

---- UPDATE / EDIT

Ok, I'm having trouble working out how to do what Justin suggested with "setting a flag" (don't quite understand that terminology tbh) in the PHP, so here's more insight on my current code (and yes it's built on Wordpress, sorry I should have said so earlier).

In my header.php I have...
Argh, having trouble..

So in my header.php I have this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/slick/slick.css"/>
<link href="/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="layoutgrid">
<link href="/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/css/layout_list.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="layoutlist">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/wpcasa/lib/assets/js/styleswitcher.js"></script>
```

Only one of those stylesheets is active at a time, whiche one is handled by the styleswitcher.js file...

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

That is not my code and as mentioned earlier I barely know anything about Javascript.

Then in my search-listings.php file I have this markup to create the selector...

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">View <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('layoutgrid'); return false;">Grid view</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('layoutlist'); return false;">List view</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

The main issue is that I need the loop counter from the PHP code at the top to run one way or another. The link provided by @aug seemed to make sense, but as far as I know I can't wrap that Javascript around the PHP to achieve what I need to do.

So to recap...

- There's a PHP while loop which displays the property listings.
- There's a PHP for loop which I wrote inside the while loop to display 2 listings each time the while loop cycles, instead of 1.
- The above worked fine until the introduction of the "list" view came about, which due to my lacking PHP knowledge had to be implemented by using a Javascript file to switch the active stylesheet.
- I now need a way to still be able to switch to the list view stylesheet, but to either change the $x < 2 to $x < 1 when the list view stylesheet is loaded, OR to be able to have an if / elseif statement that give you either $x < 2 or $x < 1 depending on which stylesheet is loaded.

I hope that makes sense, thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Any reason you need to use PHP specifically? Javascript has a way. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724606/how-to-use-javascript-to-check-and-load-css-if-not-loaded

Answer (score 1):

PHP will get processed before any HTML, Javascript or CSS does, so it has no way of telling if the CSS class exists, because it does not exist at that point in time.

In your particular situation I would dump the properties into a JSON object and handle it with Javascript.

EDIT: PHP Specific Solution

Well, I'm making an assumption from your code you are using wordpress, which it may be worth while looking into get_posts() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

With the limited info and code available, the easiest way is for you that I can see is to set a flag that designates whether or not this is a list view.

lets assume that variable is $listview which is set to true or false.

in your page's template file you can do...

```
if(!$listview) {
    //echo your extra css here...
}
```

then with your loop you created...

```
    $counter = 0;
    if(!$listview) { $hr_counter = 1; } else { $hr_counter = 2; }
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    // MaxIT - Shows 2 listings per loop instead of 2
    for ($x = 0; $x < $hr_counter; $x++) {

        // Increase loop counter
        $counter++;

        the_post();

        // Include listing loop template
        get_template_part( 'loop', 'listing' );

    } // endwhile have_posts()

    echo '<hr style="width:100%; padding-left: 40px; margin: 60px 0px;" />';
}
```

this way you will either do 2 posts then the rule, or 1 post then the rule.

Without seeing more of the code there isn't much else I can assist with in your specific situation.

Hope that helps or gets you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As stated though I'm not really familiar with using Javascript other than dropping in .js files and loading them with HTML. Could you please elaborate or point me in the right direction on what to be searching for to achieve what I wrote in my OP? Cheers.

Comment: Updated answer with a more in depth and PHP specific response.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks once again, I'll give that a try today and let you know how I go.

Comment: Not so well, but I have now updated my original post to include more code and (hopefully) a better explanation of what is currently happening, and what I need to happen. Thanks again!