# Check css file loaded or not using document.styleSheets

Tags: javascript, css

I am checking document.styleSheets for finding whether the file is loaded or not. I am doing,

```
for (var i = 0, iLen = document.styleSheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    if (!sheet.href) {
        continue;
    }
    if (sheet.href.indexOf('mypath') > -1 && sheet.rules.length > 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But its not working. Is there a way?

Comment: externally linked css do not have `rules` set, at least in Chrome it doesn't, do not know about the other browsers

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724606/how-to-use-javascript-to-check-and-load-css-if-not-loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code ant it works for me, ( on chrome, with internal css ), but it fails when using external css loaded from CDN's, so i would guess your problem is "rules" property as mentioned by @PatrickEvans.

If you don't find any other good way, then you may add an element to the page that doesn't affect the page display, but can be checked for a change.

e.g add a specific css rule like this.

```
html body div#my_stylesheet_name {
    width: 112px !important;//random width that is unlikely overwritten by another css
}
<div id="my_stylesheet_name" style="height:0; width: 0;display: none;"></div>

//then use javascript timer/interval to check if 
element with id of "my_stylesheet_name" has width of 112, if so, then it means css has loaded.
```

Edit - If you dont have any other option, you may consider something like this ( i havent used it myself before so test browser compatibility before using it )

1) create the element using JS

2) add on error and onload events, and use those to do your magic

```
    var link;
    link = document.createElement("link");
    link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    link.onload=function( evt ) {
        console.log("LINK LOADED", evt );
    };
    link.onerror=function( evt  ) {
        console.log("LINK Error", evt );
    };
    link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    link.setAttribute("href", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: @user960567 Updated my post with another potential solution